# Python - getting keys AND subkeys from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, get, key

I've got a piece of JSON file, and since JSON is a dict, I want to get keys and subkeys from it.

JSON Code:

```json
{
    "Image": {
        "URL / Path": "",
        "Max_Width": 300
    },
    "Font": {
...
```

What I want to achieve: `["Image", "Url / Path", "Max_Width", "Font", ..."]`

What I have currently: `["Image", "Font", ...]`. I've used `l=[y for y in __import__('json').load(open(r'FilePath', 'r')).keys()];l` for that.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the depth of a dictionary, you can just do something like this:

```
data = {
        "Image": {
            "URL / Path": "",
            "Max_Width": 300
        },
        "Font": {}
}
all_keys = []
for k in data:
    all_keys.append(k)
    for k1 in data[k]:
        all_keys.append(k1)
```

This goes down to the second level, iterates through each key, and adds it to the result. However, if you have multiple (and variable amounts) of levels in your JSON, then you'll have to use recursion to get all the keys.

Answer (score 1):

The function below returns all of the keys in a dict `dct` regardless of the depth:

```
def accumulate_keys(dct): # returns all the keys
    key_list = []
    def accumulate_keys_recursive(dct): # will accumulate keys in key_list
        for key in dct.keys():
            if isinstance(dct[key], dict):
                accumulate_keys_recursive(dct[key])
            else:
                key_list.append(key)
    accumulate_keys_recursive(dct)
    return key_list
print(accumulate_keys(dct))
```